# If there are many label in a tkinter window how to identify them individually?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my GUI application.There are two windows(main window and toplevel).In main window i have button named as label.If the user click on it a label would be formed on a toplevel window.For example if he clicks 4 times on that button,4 labels would be formed on toplevel window.I binded middle button of mouse to that label if he clicks on that label(in Toplevel window) properties would be shown on main window.My question is how to identify that the user has clicked which label and respectively update that label appropriately.

```
class Frame2:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.list=["label","Button","Entry","Text","Frame","RadioButton","Checkbutton","Canvas","LabelFrame","Notebook","ScaleWidget"]
        self.w2=root
        self.w2.state('zoomed')
        self.w2.title("IDE")
        self.w2.configure(background="white")
        self.projectwindow()
        self.tools()
        #=============
    def projectwindow(self):
        self.workingarea=Toplevel(self.w2)
        self.workingarea.geometry('930x660+5+25')
        #================
    def tools(self):
        self.prop=ttk.Notebook(self.w2,width=self.w2.winfo_screenwidth()-int(self.w2.winfo_screenwidth()*0.7),height=self.w2.winfo_screenheight())
        self.prop.place(x=self.w2.winfo_screenwidth()-int(self.w2.winfo_screenwidth()*0.3),y=0)
        self.widgets=Frame(self.prop,bg="white")
        self.root_properties=Frame(self.prop,bg="white")
        self.properties=Frame(self.prop)
        self.prop.add(self.widgets,text='Widgets',compound=TOP)
        self.prop.add(self.root_properties,text='Root Window Properties',compound=TOP)
        self.prop.add(self.properties,text='Properties',compound=TOP)
        #=========
        self.widget_section=LabelFrame(self.widgets,text='TK Widgets',padx=5,pady=15,bg='white')
        self.widget_section.place(x=10,y=10)
        self.obj=labels(self.workingarea,self.properties)
        for self.i in range(11):
            self.btn_widgets=Button(self.widget_section,text=self.list[self.i], borderwidth=2, relief="groove",width=33,font=("",14,""),command=self.obj.label)
            self.btn_widgets.grid(row=self.i,column=0,pady=2)
        #=====================
        self.title="Tkinter"
        self.bgcolor="white"
        self.geometry="930x660+5+25"
        self.var=StringVar(self.root_properties)
        self.var.set("True")
        #===========
        self.lbl_title=Label(self.root_properties,text="Title",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_title.place(x=10,y=10)
        self.lbl_bgcolor=Label(self.root_properties,text="Background Colour",font=("",13,""),width=18,anchor="w",bg="white")
        self.lbl_bgcolor.place(x=10,y=50)
        self.ety_title=Entry(self.root_properties,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_title.place(x=190,y=10)
        self.ety_bgcolor=Entry(self.root_properties,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_bgcolor.place(x=190,y=51)
        self.lbl_bghint=Label(self.root_properties,text="Mention background color \nas name or in hexadecimal",width=25,bg="white")
        self.lbl_bghint.place(x=190,y=75)
        self.lbl_resize=Label(self.root_properties,text="Resizable",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_resize.place(x=10,y=110)
        self.opt_menu=OptionMenu(self.root_properties, self.var, "True", "False")
        self.opt_menu.config(width=24, relief="groove",bg="white",highlightthickness=0)
        self.opt_menu.place(x=190,y=117)
        self.lbl_geometry=Label(self.root_properties,text="Geometry",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_geometry.place(x=10,y=170)
        self.ety_geom=Entry(self.root_properties,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_geom.place(x=190,y=170)
        self.geomhint=Label(self.root_properties,text="Mention Geometry in axb format.\nEg :  400x500",width=25,bg="white")
        self.geomhint.place(x=190,y=200)
        self.btn_run=Button(self.widgets,text="Run",command=self.write, borderwidth=2, relief="groove",width="20",bg="white")
        self.btn_run.place(x=150,y=650)

#==========This is a separate file label.py======================
from tkinter import *
from dnd import *
class labels:
    def __init__(self,root,prop):
        self.root=root
        self.prop=prop
        self.counter=1
    #=========================
    def fcounter(self):
        self.counter+=1
    #-----------------
    def label(self):
        self.name_var="label"+str(self.counter)
        self.name_var=Label(self.root,text='Label'+str(self.counter))
        self.name_var.pack()
        self.name_var.bind("<Button-2>",self.lbl_property)
        make_draggable(self.name_var)
        self.fcounter()
    def lbl_property(self,event):
        #====================
        self.lbl_variable=Label(self.prop,text="Variable",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_variable.place(x=10,y=10)
        self.lbl_bgcolor=Label(self.prop,text="Background Color",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_bgcolor.place(x=10,y=50)
        self.lbl_fgcolor=Label(self.prop,text="Text Color",font=("",13,""),width=18,anchor="w",bg="white")
        self.lbl_fgcolor.place(x=10,y=90)
        self.lbl_width=Label(self.prop,text="Width",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_width.place(x=10,y=130)
        self.lbl_height=Label(self.prop,text="Height",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_height.place(x=10,y=170)
        self.lbl_anchor=Label(self.prop,text="Anchor",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_anchor.place(x=10,y=210)

        #======================
        self.loc_var1=StringVar(self.prop)
        self.loc_var1.set("CENTER")
        self.bgcolor="white"
        self.fgcolor="black"
        self.width=1
        self.height=1
        #==========================
        self.ety_variable=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_variable.place(x=190,y=10)
        self.ety_variable.insert(0,self.name_var)
        self.ety_bgcolor=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_bgcolor.place(x=190,y=50)
        self.ety_fgcolor=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_fgcolor.place(x=190,y=90)
        self.ety_width=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_width.place(x=190,y=130)
        self.ety_height=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_height.place(x=190,y=170)
        self.opt_anchor=OptionMenu(self.prop,self.loc_var1,"CENTER","N","S","W","E","NE","NW","SW","SE")
        self.opt_anchor.config(width=24, relief="groove",bg="white",highlightthickness=0)
        self.opt_anchor.place(x=190,y=210)
    #===========
        self.btn_apply=Button(self.prop,text="Apply",command=self.apply, borderwidth=2, relief="groove",width="20",bg="white")
        self.btn_apply.place(x=150,y=650)
    #=================
    def apply(self):
        if self.ety_bgcolor.get()!="":
            self.bgcolor=self.ety_bgcolor.get()
        if self.ety_fgcolor.get()!="":
            self.fgcolor=self.ety_fgcolor.get()
        if self.ety_width.get()!="":
            self.width=self.ety_width.get()
        if self.ety_height.get()!="":
            self.height=self.ety_height.get()
        self.name_var.configure(bg=self.bgcolor,fg=self.fgcolor,width=self.width,height=self.height)
```

Comment: you can create button and later assign function using this button as one of arguments in function - `button["command"] = function`.You can use `lambda` to assign to Button function with arguments - `button["command"] = lambda: function(button)`.

Comment: I am implemented my code as object oriented like if the user click on a  button an object of class labels would be created and from that label function would be called from it to create label.For instance,if the user creates 50+label i can't create that much variable.

Comment: if you have to keep many items then you always use list (or dictionary). But in your situation it is more useful to use button as argument in function so it will have access to clicked button - `your_button["command"] = lambda: function(your_button).`

Comment: when you use `bind` then it send event which has information about clicked widgets - `event.widget` - and you have access to clicked widget.

Comment: BTW: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - `class Labels` - similar to classes `Button`, `Label`, `OptionMenu`. And then it is easier to recognize class in code. Even SO uses different color for classes. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `bind` then it sends event and it has `event.widget` which gives you access to clicked button.

If you use `command=` when you can assign function after creating button and use this button as argument in function

```
my_button = tk.Button(...)
my_button["command"] = lambda: my_function(my_button)
```